# SQL script fails import in Teradata 15 but succeeds in 14

Tags: teradata

I recently updated one of my two work computers to Teradata v15. Given the radical difference in the GUI between Teradata SQL Assistant v14 & Teradata Studio v15 I wanted to try and run a script of mine as a test case to figure out how things had changed. Unfortunately I didn't get very far, when I attempted to import some needed data from a tab delimited TXT file the import failed with the error "[5666 : HY000] LOBs are not allowed in indexes.".

The field that is supposed to be getting filled is defined as VARCHAR(11), all the values in the TXT are 11 characters (they're fixed IDs). The data successfully imported when I ran the same logic in TSA 14. That being the case I'm thinking (hoping) something is off in my settings, but Google hasn't turned up any results that are helpful.

For reference the SQL in question is below:

```
CREATE SET TABLE HP_TX_OWN_TABLES.SRI_TX088, NO FALLBACK , 
    NO BEFORE JOURNAL, 
    NO AFTER JOURNAL, 
    CHECKSUM = DEFAULT 
    ( 
        MEM_ID VARCHAR(11)   
    ) 
PRIMARY INDEX (MEM_ID);

INSERT INTO HP_TX_OWN_TABLES.SRI_TX088 VALUES (?);
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is that you switched versions (14 to 15).  The real issue is that you switched tools (SQL Assistant to Teradata Studio).  The radical difference between SQL Assistant and Teradata Studio extends to more than just the GUI

Comment: The issue was IT buried the TSA exe. Once I was in the same tool there was no issue.